# Returning None value without me asking for it

Tags: python

```
def city_country(city, country):
    message = print(f"{city} is in the {country}! ")
    return message

city_n = input("What is the city called? ")
country_n = input("Where is it located? ")

final_message = city_country(city_n , country_n)
print(final_message)
```

It gives me None when it's not supposed to. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Line 2: Variable `message` is the returned value of the function `print`. But `print` returns `None` so you get `None` back.

Comment: the `print` function does not return anything, so you are getting `None`

Comment: You want the `input()` function, not the `print()` function :)

Comment: @khuynh well, it returns `None`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga implicit None d:

Answer (score 0):

You can not define the variable as a print function, as print does not return anything, it just prints something

Comment: The print function returns `None`. All functions without an explicit return will return `None` in Python.

Comment: Of course you *can*. `print` returns `None` always though, so it's not very useful